# C manipulating "object" in function

Tags: c, pointers

I am back with another "why this works but this doesn't" question. I am trying to structure my C code so as to be able to build up complexity and work with pointers to structs, so having functions like

```
Spline *new_spline() {
    \\code to set up "object" here
    Spline *toReturn = malloc(sizeof(*toReturn));        
    if (toReturn == NULL) perror("malloc toReturn failed in new_spline()\n");
    toReturn->x_vals = x_vals; \\double*
    toReturn->y_vals = y_vals; \\double*
    toReturn->coeffs = coeffs; \\double*
    toReturn->lines = lines; \\int
    toReturn->xmin = xmin; \\double
    toReturn->xmax = xmax;  \\double
    return toReturn;
}
```

and equivalently

```
int free_spline(Spline *s) {
    free(s->x_vals);
    free(s->y_vals);
    free(s->coeffs);
    free(s);
    s = NULL;
    return 0;
}
```

Now my problem comes when I try to modify a spline through this function:

```
int scale_spline(Spline *spline, double scale_fac) {
    double *ys = malloc(spline->lines * sizeof(*ys));
    if (ys == NULL) {
        printf("err in scale_spline()\n");
        exit(0);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < spline->lines; i++) {
        ys[i] = scale_fac * spline->y_vals[i];
    }
    Spline *toReturn = new_spline(spline->lines, spline->x_vals, ys);
    free_spline(spline);
    free(ys);
    *spline = *toReturn;
    return 0;
}
```

There is no error initially and the modification appears to work, but an unrelated malloc() subsequently fails later in the code, giving a segfault. I assume this is because free_spline() followed by *spline = *toReturn does not do what I want it to, which is to make this pointer point to the data pointed to by *toReturn. The version of this function that works is:

```
int scale_spline(Spline **spline, double scale_fac) {
    double *ys = malloc((*spline)->lines * sizeof(*ys));
    if (ys == NULL) {
        printf("err in scale_spline()\n");
        exit(0);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < (*spline)->lines; i++) {
        ys[i] = scale_fac * (*spline)->y_vals[i];
    }
    Spline *toReturn = new_spline((*spline)->lines, (*spline)->x_vals, ys);
    free_spline(*spline);
    free(ys);
    *spline = toReturn;
    return 0;
}
```

Why exactly is the first version of scale_spline() bad and how to modify it to still work with a Spline*? There is likely to be a lot wrong with this code, so any critique would be welcome. Thank you!

Comment: Please post real code. `\\ ` is not a comment-introducer, you meant `//`.

Comment: And post a *complete* example.  Because this looks suspect:  `toReturn->x_vals = x_vals; \\double*`  Nevermind the `\\ ` "comment", where does `x_vals` come from?

Comment: You're `free`ing `x_vals`, `y_vals`, and `coeffs`, but don't allocate them anywhere.  That's a problem.

Comment: Don't use global variables unless you are completely sure that they are appropriate. Not just to avoid passing parameters to functions, or to avoid declaring them inside a function. Note that debugging is a lot harder when you have global variables, and also the code is way harder to read and more importanty it's quite easy to introduce a bug.

Answer (score 0):

Note that with:

```
new_spline(spline->lines, spline->x_vals, ys);
```

you are *not* copying `spline->x_vals`; you are merely using the same set of x values in the new spline! So if you free the old spline with `free_spline`, you free the x values and if you free the new spline, the x values have already been freed, causing a problem.

To copy it, add in `new_spline`:

```
double *x_valsnew= malloc(lines, sizeof(double)); // or xmin?
memcpy(x_valsnew, x_vals, lines*sizeof(double));
```

(How many to allocate may be different from `lines`; that is up to you. The point is you must allocate new memory and copy.)

Answer (score 0):

In second function with pointer to pointer you change input pointer where it points to. When function is executed, input pointer gets actual new value outside this function.

First function could work if you do at the end only `spline = toReturn` but because `spline` is copied value as parameter, value outside this function has no sense.

With double pointer, you can achieve to change where pointer points outside function.

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies here:

```
free_spline(spline);
free(ys);
*spline = *toReturn;
```

In `free_spline(spline);`, you explicitely end in calling `free(spline)`. So you have completely freed where `spline` initially pointed at. When you later copy `toReturn` to `spline` as a struct copy, you do copy to a dangling pointer, which is Undefined Behaviour. If you want to simply modify the original `Spline` struct, you should do:

```
    Spline *toReturn = new_spline(spline->lines, spline->x_vals, ys); // compute new spline
    free(spline->x_vals);         // free internals of original one
    free(spline->y_vals);
    free(spline->coeffs);
    free(ys);                     // free intermediate array
    *spline = *toReturn;          // copy the internals to original spline
    free(toReturn);               // free the temp one
    return 0;
}
```

Or if only `y_vals` have changed:

```
    free(spline->y_vals);
    spline->y_vals = ys;
    return 0
}
```